# Why "null" can't be the default value of a nullable column?

Tags: orm, prisma

Consider this schema:

```
model Comment {
  id        Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  reply     Comment?   @relation(fields: [replyId], references: [id], onDelete: SetNull)
  replyId   Int?       @default(null)
  comment   String
}
```

Here both `reply` and `replyId` are nullable. When I migrate I get this error:

```
error: Error parsing attribute "@default": Expected a numeric value, but received literal value "Null".
  -->  schema.prisma:70
   |
69 |   reply     Comment? @relation(fields: [replyId], references: [id], onDelete: SetNull)
70 |   replyId   Int?     @default(null)
   |
```

Why?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You don't really need to specify a null default value for an optional field. If you don't specify  `Comment` relation or explicitly provide the `replyId` value for a record, then the value of `replyId` is automatically null. This is true for optional fields that are not acting as foreign keys as well.

So, the behavior you want would be there automatically, there's no need to define `@default(null)`.

Comment: Thank you. you are the only person that answers my Prisma questions:). I thought that because replyId is an integer, its default value is 0.

Comment: Optional fields, regardless of the type are nullable and defaults to null.  And happy to help :D

Comment: yep the "Int?" actually means, set to null if nothing is provided.

Comment: There is however a use case where someone would want to have NULL as default rather than undefine. For instance, PostgreSQL guarantees 'uniqueness' for NULL  fields but not for undefined.

Comment: I have same problem. I follow this answer to used `DateTime?` optional type data and work to create default `NULL` :D

Comment: this is not true for mongodb